# Sencha JSON to SelectField Options

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2

I have a call to my data layer that brings back json object. I need to take this object and convert it to an options array in my selectField. This json object has a district name and a districtID - that is all that is in the object.

Comment: Can you please post your JSON here?

Comment: "[{"DistrictID":1,"District":"Nebraska"},{"DistrictID":2,"District":"Michigan"},{"DistrictID":3,"District":"New York"},{"DistrictID":4,"District":"Washington"}]"

Comment: You'r json is INVALID. Just check it by pasting it on jsonlint.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in selectfield config, set valueField to 'DistrictID' and displayField to 'District'
then just selectField.setOptions(json)